# Problem when setting up Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a problem when setting up Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud. When I use this command:-

```
euca-authorize default -P tcp -p 22 -s 0.0.0.0/0
```

The system says:-

```
EC2_ACCESS_KEY environment variable must be set.
```

Can anyone help me on this? How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on a blog in some comments about setting up Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud:

Question:

> I try to start a intance of the emi,
>   but i got :
>
> “EC2_ACCESS_KEY environment variable
>   must be set”.
>
> Can you help me with this ? Reply

Answer:

> This is set in eucarc, the “. eucarc”
>   should source the required env
>   variables and set them for further
>   commands.

Maybe this is usefull for you

Comment: Thank you Diskilla, but I don't know how to source the required env variables. Can you show me how to do it? 

Sorry, I'm quite new in this. 

Patrick

Comment: Hi Patrick do you have how to for cloud computing with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the reply.

I manage to solve this problem. Just use the following command:-

```
source ~/.euca/eucarc
```

I found the following information from the internet:-

```
...should have created a "eucarc" file with important environment variable information within it. You will need to source the eucarc to run the ec2tools in your environment...
```

Thank you.

Patrick.